# Why do suspending functions throw exceptions in finally

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-coroutines

As the title says, why do suspending functions throw exceptions in `finally`?

With regular functions, the `finally`-block executes all of them:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        println("Caught $exception")
    }
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
        launch {
            // the first child
            try {
                println("inside try")
                delay(1000)
            } finally {

                println("Children are cancelled, but exception is not handled until all children terminate")

                Thread.sleep(1000)
                println("thread.sleep executed")
                //foo()
                println("The first child finished its non cancellable block")

            }
        }
        launch {
            // the second child
            delay(10)
            println("Second child throws an exception")
            throw ArithmeticException()
        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000000)
    println("complete")
}
```

Here, for example, when I do `Thread.sleep(1000)` it prints:

> "The first child finished its non cancellable block"

but if I change that line to `delay(1000)`, it does not.

From my understanding, in a `finally`-block, the exception, if it exists, is thrown after executing the entire block.

But in this case, `delay` causes this exception to be thrown early.

On the other hand, `Thread.sleep` does not.

Can someone help explain?

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 5):

Suspending functions in Kotlin work differently than blocking function.
When you cancel a `Job`, at the first suspension after the cancellation the execution will be stopped, **even** if you are in a `finally` block. If you use `Thread.sleep(1000)` instead of `delay(1000)` in your `finally` block, there are no suspensions taking place, because `Thread.sleep()` is **blocking**, not suspending, so your whole `finally` block gets executed.

Note that using blocking functions inside of suspending functions is an anti-pattern and should be avoided!!

To achieve this desired behavior without using blocking functions, use `withContext(NonCancellable) {...}` as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#cancellation-and-exceptions).

Your example code should look like this:

```
fun main() {
  val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    println("Caught $exception")
  }
  val job = GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
    launch {
      // the first child
      try {
        println("inside try")
        delay(1000000)
      } finally {
        withContext(NonCancellable) {
          println("Children are cancelled, but exception is not handled until all children terminate")

          delay(1000) // This suspension cannot be cancelled
          println("delay executed")
          //foo()
          println("The first child finished its non cancellable block")
        }
      }
    }
    launch {
      // the second child
      delay(10)
      println("Second child throws an exception")
      throw ArithmeticException()
    }
  }

  Thread.sleep(1000000)
  println("complete")
}
```

The output:

```
inside try
Second child throws an exception
Children are cancelled, but exception is not handled until all children terminate
delay executed
The first child finished its non cancellable block
Caught java.lang.ArithmeticException
```

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, in a `finally`-block, the exception, if it exists, is thrown after executing the entire block.

This is not true. If a `finally` block throws an exception, it causes the `finally` block to terminate abruptly with that exception. Any exception that was thrown within `try` is thus discarded. This is exactly what happens in your case: the `finally` block of the first child coroutine receives a `CancellationException` on the `delay(1000)` line. `Thread.sleep(1000)` is a blocking, non-cancellable function, therefore it doesn't observe the cancellation.

You probably mixed up this with the fact that, if the `try` block throws an exception, then first the complete `finally` block is executed before throwing the exception. The `finally` block is required to complete normally in order for this to happen.

So I believe you aren't describing any difference in the behavior of plain and suspendable functions.

Comment: Aha! This would make much more sense. It sounds like there is some sort of implicit `isActive` or similar function that makes sure the current coroutine and its parent are both not yet cancelled (as in, they have not been explicitly cancelled or run into an exception)

Comment: The `isActive` flag is in direct parallel to the `Thread.isInterrupted()` flag. You must explicitly check it in your coroutine code, or call a suspendable function that checks it for you. Such a function is identifiable by declaring to be cancellable.

Comment: So suspending functions implicitly call it?

Comment: Nothing is implicit. Just as your own function would have to explicitly check it and react by throwing a `CancellationException`, a standard library function does it as well. Either that or you suspend the coroutine by calling `suspendCancellableCoroutine`.